# Bootstrap3 ASP.NET Validation display validation to right of control

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like the validation error text to appear to the right form controls, but instead it appears under. In Bootstrap 2 there was a style called help-inline that appeared to do this, but it has been removed from version 3.

The solution I have right now is ok -- at medium and large resolution it looks the way I want it:

```
<div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
      <div class="col-md-4">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "40" })
      </div>
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger col-md-6 form-control-static" })
</div>
```

This produces:

[image]

The problem is that when the screen width is reduced, the ValidationMessage span takes up an extra line even when hidden -- which grows the height of the form. Which you can see if you look at the spacing after the first and last names which use the above syntax, opposed to City which uses the more common syntax:

[image]

Is there way of updating the more common syntax of:

```
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
  <div class="col-md-10">
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the rendered HTML from the example above:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Address_City">City</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Address_City" name="Address.City" type="text" value="RCQXNEZMTBSURAX" />
      <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Address.City" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

So there a way to have the validation appear to the right of the control (inline) without creating that extra line at reduced width?

Comment: Have a look at `pull-right`

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-help-text There is that, but it's not exactly what you are requesting.

Comment: @lzzy, pull-right still puts it on the next line, but right justified.

Comment: @Aibrean, help-block is the same behavior as not having it, it breaks a new line.